# grep multiple patterns from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I ran a BLAST search on NCBI and downloaded the results as an xml file. From this file, I need the species name, with its corresponding sequence.

The species name has `<Hit_def>` as a pattern, while the matching sequence has `<Hsp_qseq>` as the pattern, but both of these are separated by some lines. Is there a way to `grep` (or `awk`) `<Hit_def>` followed by `<Hsp_qseq>` such that it joins the two lines and gives me the information for each species?

As suggested, I am including a sample of the actual input file -
`<Hit_def>` protein name [Homo sapiens] `</Hit_def>`

`<Hit_accession>` BAG72649 `</Hit_accession>`

`<Hit_len>` 2004 `</Hit_len>`

`<Hit_hsps>`

`<Hsp>`

`<Hsp_num>` 1 `</Hsp_num>`

`<Hsp_qseq>` protein sequence `</Hsp_qseq>`

The output I expect is -

`<Hit_def>` protein name [Homo sapiens] `<\Hit_def>`

`<Hsp_qseq>`protein_sequence `<\Hsp_qseq>`

`<Hit_def>`  protein name [Mus musculus] `<\Hit_def>`

`<Hsp_qseq>` protein_sequence `<\Hsp_qseq>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, could you please post your sample Input_file with code tags, as it is not clear.

Comment: `<Hit_def>` protein name [Homo sapiens]  `</Hit_def>`  `<Hit_accession>` BAG72649 `</Hit_accession>`
 `<Hit_len>` 2004 `</Hit_len>`
  `<Hit_hsps>` 
    `<Hsp>` 
      `<Hsp_num>` 1 `</Hsp_num>`
`<Hsp_qseq>` protein sequence `</Hsp_qseq>` 
      Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your post with code tags, so that all could be aware of your requirement.

Comment: I have added all the code tags that I felt were needed. Could you please specify where you need code tags? Thanks.

Comment: our concern is that you should put sample Input which you have put in above comment into your post in code tags. So usually any sample input/commands/codes should be covered with code tags.

Comment: Dear Ravinder, I have made the edit. Kindly let me know if you face any problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ grep '\(<Hit_def>\|<Hsp_qseq>\)' file
<Hit_def> protein name [Homo sapiens] </Hit_def>
<Hsp_qseq> protein sequence </Hsp_qseq>
```

Explained:

- `grep` using `grep`
- `'` single quotes around the pattern (unless you need shell expansion)
- `\(` BRE (*basic regex*, as opposed to ERE *extended regex* in `grep -E`) requires escaping the grouping characters `()` as well as the OR operator `|`
- `<Hit_def>`, `<Hsp_qseq>` the keywords you need

Comment: Thanks a lot, James. That is exactly what I was looking for.